# getServerSideProps does not fetch the data at first time in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch

I have a component that fetch data from my MongoDB database.After fetching the data, I want to create some cards by this data. My backend server is working. Also I connect my frontend to backend.

```js
import axios from "axios";
import Cards from "../components/Cards";
import CarouselComponent from "../components/Carousel";
import { Navbar } from "../components/Navbar";

export default function Home({ products }) {
  console.log(products);
  return (
    <div className="">
      <Navbar />
      <CarouselComponent />
      {/* <Cards products={products} /> */}
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // Fetch data from external API
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/products`);
  const data = await res.json();

  // Pass data to the page via props
  return { props: { products: data } };
}
```

[image]
**products** prop is turns me empty object. But when I refresh the page second time, it brings me all the products. I tested it in postman, also in postman I can get all the products. Why when I stop the server and start it again it doesn't fetch the products?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html)  can help.

Comment: @dariosicily I know how to do it in reactjs. It is serverside rendering. When I make call to https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5, it fetch all of them and all users come. But when I make this call to localstorage it doesn't fetch them. i don't understand the relation with this link you send

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**
I added

```js
 await dbConnect();
```

to

```js
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // Fetch data from external API
  await dbConnect();
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/products`);
  const data = await res.json();

  // Pass data to the page via props
  return { props: { products: data } };
}
```

I think my mistake was to try fetching data before connecting to server

Comment: Wouldn't be better to call the `dbConnect` function in the API Route?